# redirect to last page not working on python social auth

Tags: python, django, redirect, python-social-auth

I'm using python social auth to use social logins but I'm unable to redirect to the last page after successful login.

For instance if I'm on the following page `http://localhost:8000/docprofile/14/`and click the login button, instead of redirecting me to the last page `http://localhost:8000/docprofile/14/` it redirects me to the login page.

If I put this:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}"> | Login with Facebook</a>
```

It redirects to the login page and the url ends with strange characters:

```
http://localhost:8000/login/#_=_
```

I also tried this:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.get_full_path }}"> | Login with Facebook</a>
```

This time it does take the path of the `/docprofile/14` but still doesn't redirect me back and takes me to the login page with the url `http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/docprofile/14/#_=_`

Comment: Beside the redirect issue, the authentication is working fine?

Comment: @omab Yes, the authentication is working fine. It's just the redirection is the issue!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

What I had to do was strip off the next parameter from the query string in my GET and modify the html to include it in the template like this

```
def home(request):
    c = context()
    if request.GET.get('next'):
        c = context(next=request.GET['next'])

    return render_to_response('home.html',
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request, c))

def context(**extra):
    return dict({
        'available_backends': load_backends(settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS)
    }, **extra)
```

And my template now gets the next parameter from the context and when i log in the redirect works.

```
<a class="col-md-2 btn btn-default" name="{{ backend|backend_class }}" href="{% url "social:begin" backend=name %}?next={{next}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include this in head of your template of the redirected page -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (window.location.hash == '#_=_') {
      window.location.hash = '';
   }
</script>`
```

It will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<a class="fb-login-placeholder" href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.GET.next }}">| Login with Facebook</a>
```

that is instead of `request.path` you need `request.GET.next`.
And indeed, to get rid of the funny characters use @AshishGupta's answer.